# tomcat 5.5 response header cache

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, response

I wanna know please how this "expires times" has generated 
(please see the reponse header in the screen)

Expires:Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 ACT

The application is two slow. everytime sends 304 (for .js, .css) but it's take a long time to make the 304 reponse and return 0 Bit (in size).

what is the best practice to do cache with tomcat? what i have to change in my application? 
i wanna the .js and .css to be cached, and check the server for a new version every time sometimes has changed or after a certain delay.

can you please tell me if there is something wrong with the request/response header in the image below?

can't understand why the latency is too high 781 ms and finally get 0Bit. why all this times?

the response screen : 
http://postimg.org/image/jce62vqbz/

tomcat : 5.5

jdk : 1.6

thanks a lot, 
best regards.

Answer (score 1):

in your dynamic page creation you are setting negative expires which shall generate past date from 1969. i think you are using

> response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);

that means the page already expires and it will reload  everything(include js,css) each time.

so please remove it. it will solve your issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. 

i have used another tomcat directory (with the same version of tomcat), and i deployed the application war (without any change from the prod server) and this line (Expires:Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 ACT) it's just disapair. 

Wanna know please, if this property (that you said) can be set to tomcat configuration directly? and if it can have a relation with the SSL certification (https)?